# A jquery validator method that do not accept pure number or pure special characters but accepts if there is a letter on it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

To be exact, if the user inputs a "123", this is invalid because no letters are existing on the input. But if the user inputs a "D123", this is valid because a letter is existing on the input. To do that, I can use this

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod ("numbernot",function(value, element)
{
return this.optional(element) || /^(?![0-9]*$)[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$/i.test(value);
}, "INVALID");
```

but the problem in that method is, special characters are not allowed, how can I make it accepts the special characters ' and - ONLY.
Same on the rules above if the user input a "-'--" this is invalid because its a pure special character, but if user input a "-'D-" this is valid because it has a letter on it.

Another and last problem, I also want it to accept another language lets say a Japanese word like "こんにちは". Thank you, and Im so sorry if my question is too brutal.

Comment: sweaver2112, thank you so much!, the first problem is solve. But how can I make it accepts all possible language?

Comment: Japanese letters is accepted and valid, but if i input a letter with diacritic mark like "è", it tells me that it is invalid. :(

Comment: Aren't you looking to just match any string of chars that contains a digit? `/^.*\d.*$/`? Also, do you mean to match chars from outside BMP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/^(?=.*[a-zA-Z\u3000-\u303F\u3040-\u309F\u30A0-\u30FF\uFF00-\uFFEF\u4E00-\u9FAF\u2605-\u2606\u2190-\u2195\u203B])[\w\-'\u3000-\u303F\u3040-\u309F\u30A0-\u30FF\uFF00-\uFFEF\u4E00-\u9FAF\u2605-\u2606\u2190-\u2195\u203B]+$/
```

1. lookahead to see an ascii letter or japanese char
2. consume `\w` (ascii alphanumerics) or japanese chars, or `-`, or `'`, limit to whole string with anchors.

*[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iF9jB8/5) //
japanese unicode adapted from [here](https://gist.github.com/ryanmcgrath/982242)*